# entitiy manager: persist doesn't work, no error message

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

I have a problem with one of my action within a controller. I want to change one single attribute of an object (publish date of a small ad).

I get a specific small ad from the repository, change the value of the attribute and than the entity manager should persist the object. This works fine with a few other attributes, but not with the date `validTo`.

My problem is now, that I don't get any error message. When I write the value of each step to a log file, it has the correct value. Even when I get the attribute via `$smallad->getValidTo()` after the `$em->flush()` method (to shorten the code I removed all the logging lines). But the I don't get any changes in the database and the value isn't persisted.

I use this kind of action controller for changing some single values of attributes in a few other controllers without having any problems. And without a proper error message I don't have a clue where to start looking for a solution. Any ideas?

```
public function extendAction($id)
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:SmallAd');
    $smallad = $repository->findOneBy(array('id'=>$id));

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $date = $smallad->getValidTo()->modify('+31 days');
    $smallad->setValidTo($date);
    $em->persist($smallad);
    $em->flush();

    return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('member'));
}
```

Comment: Just a small note - you do not need `persist()` in this case since you're working on an entity that is already managed because you retrieved it using the `findOneBy()` method.  You can also shorten your `findOneBy()` command with `$smalladd = $repository->find($id);` as long as you have `$id` defined as your main `Id` value on your entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctrine 2 uses object references to detect when a date property has been changed and thus needs to have the database update: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html

It is a bit counter intuitive.  You updated the date but kept the same date object and thus no change.  Easy enough to fix by cloning the date:

```
$date = $smallad->getValidTo()->modify('+31 days');
$smallad->setValidTo(clone $date);
```

Comment: If php>=5.5 is used, it is good to consider using `DateTimeImmutable`. I haven't tested it with Doctrine, but there seems to be a library adding support for it here - https://github.com/VasekPurchart/Doctrine-Date-Time-Immutable-Types